# How to pass command line arguments to a jar in aws beanstalk from jenkins pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jenkins-plugins

i am able to transfer files from my Jenkins to AWS S3 bucket.Also i am able to create an environment in AWS Elastic beanstalk and the jar is running,However suppose i want to pass any command line arguements alongwith my jar and make it run then what should be the syntax in Jenkins Pipeline declarative code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved

We need to create a Procfile which will have commands like

web: java -Xmx4096m -jar ${application-jar name}.jar

We need to zip the application jar alongwith Procfile along with any files which we are passing through command line arguments while making our application run.

This zip file once we upload to s3 bucket then in elastic beanstalk this zip file is used and the application is run by the command we pass in Procfile